# jQuery find next div within a parent of $this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I'm having troubles targeting a particular div within a loop of divs.

My code below is a single item that is duplicated many times on a page. If the span with the class of edd_price has the text 'Free' inside it I want to hide the div class 'vat' of just this item.

```
<div class="product-thumb">
  <a href="http://tb.eldo.co.uk/downloads/achieving-sales-on-the-telephone-sample-notes/">
  <div class="thum">
    <img width="185" height="150" src="blah"/>
  </div>
  <div class="title">Title goes here</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="edd_price">Free</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="vat clear">
    price excluding 20% vat                             
  </div>
</a>
```

Everything I've tried either affects nothing or all the items on the page, heres what I think should work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(".edd_price").contains("Free")) {
  $(this).parent().next('div.vat').hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your condition is not working, the contains method should be this way:

```
if ( $(".edd_price:contains(free)"))
```

Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp

In condition you have to get the element again because your **this** isn't him. This is not a callback. Then:

```
$(function() {
    if ( $(".edd_price:contains(free)")) {
        $('.edd_price:contains("Free")').parent().next('.vat').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/87qcfng8/

Ps: Your first div is not closed, so close it.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I'm still learning (as you can tell). I was on the right track but your comments have taught me the error of my ways. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The condition is:

```
if ( $(".edd_price:contains(free)"))
```

and use this inside:

```
$('.edd_price:contains("Free")').parent().next('.vat').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get parent node of the "Free" container (retrieved with `:contains("Free")` selector) and hide the next element with class `.vat`:

```
$('.edd_price:contains("Free")').parent().next('.vat').hide();
```

Here is a demo:

```js
$('.edd_price:contains("Free")').parent().next('.vat').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-thumb"> 
  <a href="http://tb.eldo.co.uk/downloads/achieving-sales-on-the-telephone-sample-notes/">
  <div class="thum">
    <img width="185" height="150" src="http://lorempixel.com/185/150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="title">Title goes here</div>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="edd_price">Free</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="vat clear">
    price excluding 20% vat                             
  </div>
</a>
```